# Instantiate prefab as a type that inherits from MonoBehaviour

Tags: unity, c#

I have a `CeilingTile` class. In this class, I have an `InstantiateCeilingLamp()` method, which instantiates from a `CeilingLamp` prefab.

Here is the code:

```
protected void InstantiateCeilingLamp()
{
    Object ceilingLampPrefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(prefabPath, typeof(GameObject));

    CeilingLamp ceilingLamp = 
        Instantiate(ceilingLampPrefab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) 
            as CeilingLamp;

    if (ceilingLamp == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to instantiate the ceiling lamp.");
        return;
    }

    ceilingLamp.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
}
```

`prefabPath` is a `const string` defined within the class.

Stepping through my code using the debugger, I can see that `ceilingLampPrefab` is non-null after executing `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(prefabPath, typeof(GameObject));`.

However, `Instantiate(...) as CeilingLamp;` returns `null`, because the instantiated prefab cannot be cast to the type `CeilingLamp`, which inherits from `MonoBehaviour`.

How should I modify my code in order to instantiate a prefab as a type that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`?

Answer (score 1):

The `CeilingLamp` prefab has the `CeilingLamp.cs` script (which inherits from `MonoBehaviour`) attached to it, so by modifying the code as follows, I am able to do what I want:

```
protected void InstantiateCeilingLamp()
{
    Object ceilingLampPrefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(prefabPath, typeof(GameObject));

    GameObject lampObject = 
        Instantiate(ceilingLampPrefab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) 
            as GameObject;

    CeilingLamp ceilingLamp = lampObject.GetComponent<CeilingLamp>();

    if (CeilingLamp == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to instantiate the ceiling lamp.");
        return;
    }

    ceilingLamp.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
}
```

Comment: I think you can simplify this substantially by making it `var ceilingLampPrefab = (CeilingLamp)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(prefabPath, typeof(CeilingLamp)` then your `Instantiate` method will return the reference to the instance's ceiling lamp script directly.